# Bake Built-in Function in Graph Editor to keyframe?

Tags: animation

I have a sine wave I generated in the graph editor for a pendulum and I was wondering if there's a way to bake the sine wave in a certain range to keyframes so I can easily edit the beginning and ending frames. Ideas?

Spencer

Comment: You can always use the cycles modifier in the graphs animation editor. Besides that, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: When I can't find a direct or inbuilt way of doing this, I simply 'trace' over the generated waveform in the Graph editor.  i.e. create an animation  channel for the pendulum and in the editor, add a keyframe for each of the sine wave's + or - extemities and adjust each of those to match the other.  If they're not being cycled you could probably make a few and duplicate those in the Dopesheet.

Comment: Further - I've had a play around with this and baked audio to keyframes which produces a pure curve in the Graph editor but no keyframes.  I'm assuming this is what you've come up against.  A curve without keyframes. I selected the object concerned and in the "Object" menu, selected -> Animation -> Bake action".  In the bake panel you enter the frame range you need, plus tick all boxes EXCEPT the one that says "Overwrite existing keyframes" or words to that effect in your version.  That converts the raw curve to a keyframed curve and might do the job for you.